# How to merge the array of lists into single column and fit it to already existing dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie to spark and scala. Please help me with this.

I have the below output with which I need to generate a new dataframe with all the features merged rather than on separate lists. Also, I need to append this dataframe to another dataframe. How can I do this in scala?

```
val tab = inter.map(_.groupBy().sum())
tab.map(_.show())

tab: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([sum(vec_0): double, sum(vec_1): double ... 2 more fields], [sum(vec_0): double, sum(vec_1): double ... 2 more fields])
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        sum(vec_0)|        sum(vec_1)|        sum(vec_2)|        sum(vec_3)|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2.5046410000000003|2.1487149999999997|1.0884870000000002|3.5877090000000003|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
|        sum(vec_0)|        sum(vec_1)|sum(vec_2)|        sum(vec_3)|
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
|0.9558040000000001|0.9843780000000002|  0.545025|0.9979860000000002|
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
res325: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
FINISHED   

    val temp = tab.map(_.alias("t").select(array("t.*") as "List"))
    temp.map(_.toDF().show(false))

    temp: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([List: array<double>], [List: array<double>])
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |List                                                                            |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003]|
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |List                                                                  |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002]|
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    res443: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
val newtable = temp.map(_.toDF("features"))
newtable.map(_.show(false))

     newtable: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([features: 
array<double>], [features: array<double>])
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |features                                                                        |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003]|
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |features                                                              |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002]|
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    res328: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
```

Expected output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003]| 
|[0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: try flatmap in place of map, it should do the flatting of arrays. like val newtable = temp.flatMap(_.toDF("features"))

Comment: I am getting the following error if I try flatMap.

found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
       val newtable = temp.flatMap(_.toDF)

Comment: How does your input look like (the temp variable)? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Yes I agree with Shaido too. temp sample should help you get solution quickly

Comment: temp is similar to newtable....I created a list by merging columns and converted it into a lists . Now I am trying get all the lists under one column so that I can append it to a dataframe.

Comment: So your goal is to create a new column in `tab` that contains a list of all values in the columns?

Comment: My goal is to create a single features/list table with each list in a different row(like the expected output mentioned above). So, the lists/features above should come under one roof. Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: The unusual point here is that you work with an array of DataFrames, normally you only have one. Is `tab` also such an array?

Comment: what is `tab` then ? you are making it so complicated. What is your initial input data that you are reading from?

Comment: added tab....it's a sum of columnwise values. My initial input is two sentences with which I am generating word vectors and summing it. As it is not related to what I want to achieve, I didn't specify. I just need these two separate feature lists into one.

Comment: From your comment it sounds like what you are doing here is very wrong. You should not have to have multiple dataframes like this. Instead, please post your initial input (your sentences) and specify what the expected output is. Maybe you are looking for [word2Vec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#word2vec)?

Comment: The mentioned word2vec is spark specific. I am using an external word2vec (google's) as it is the requirement. So, I am taking my sentences, dividing it into words, reading external word2vec and comparing against the words that I have to retrieve the 300 vector values for each word, summing it up column-wise which generates 300 vectors for a sentence and then trying to train the machine learning model with labels that I have for the sentences and summed vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

```
val fList = newtable.reduce(_.union(_))
newtable.show(false



 fList: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: array<double>]
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003]|
|[0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002]          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```